# SQL Server Routing or options

Tags: sql-server-spatial

We are looking for a way using SQL Server spatial queries (or spatial library if needed) to do the following:

We have our own set of spatial data for custom roads (single line) and many point along that road. Some are checkpoints and some are just pass throughs.

We need a way to query what the next checkpoint is heading to a destination based on a current location on that line.

Is this possible with SQL Server spatial?